# Получить индекс кнопки, которая находится в ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm

[image: Слева кнопки]

Для каждой кнопки должна выполняться своя команда, поэтому мне в VM нужно получить индекс нажимаемой кнопки. Какие существуют для этого варианты?

Comment: Сделать объект, который будет иметь контент и `ICommand`?

Comment: Зачем Index? Чем вам не угодили команды с параметрами?

Comment: Можете привести пример?

Comment: Пример чего? Этого? `class ItemViewModel { public ICommand Command {get; private set;} public string Content {get; set;}` Ну и привязка `<Button Content = "{Binding Content}" Command = "{Binding Command}">` Таким образом вы будете использовать совершенно любую логику, которую зададите в команде.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при нажатии открывается окно с расчетами, и результат расчета в том окне должен появится в TextBox к которому относится эта кнопка. Поэтому через объект не получится решить вопрос.

Comment: Ну тогда вам не "разные команды" надо, а передать в команду значение. Задавайте параметр тогда как вам посоветовали выше